# How to get state data from child to parent component?

Tags: reactjs

I have two components, TabTble and MultiSelect.
I'm rendering MultiSelect component in TabTble, so parent component is TabTble  and child component is MultiSelect.
I have some state in my child (MultiSelect) component, how to get it in TabTble component.

`const selectedData = this.state.multi;` this is state data

`const {selectedData } = this.props` in this way i passed it as props

`<MultiSelect selectedData ={ selectedData }` /> And render it in child component like this.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way of sharing state variables between components is through redux store.  The major advantage is if you have more than just 2 components, then u can use store state in all of them and modify it by dispatching actions which again will make the modified state available to all the components.

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this suppose you have these two components :

```
class TabTble extends Component  {
handleChildData = (fromMultiSelectData) => {
//Do whatever you want to do from this child data
}
return (
<MultiSelect selectedData ={ selectedData } handleChildData = {this.handleChildData}/>
);
}
```

wherease in MultiSelect component:

```
class MultiSelect extends Components {
   state = {
    localData:[] //local state data which we want to send to parent components
}
handleClick = () => {
let {localData} = this.state;
this.props.handleChildData(localStateData)
}
render(){
let {selectedData} = this.props;
return(
somechild
//Note you need some event handler like onChange,onClick to pass this data up
<div onClick={this.handleClick}>Send Data to parent</div> //you can pass any other data from here
)
}
}
```

// Note this design pattern is not good while designing react code. Its always recommended when you have such prop drill down or use good state management either context api or redux.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change a bit your code. Put the states who goes to change in Parent and pass it as a props to child, in child you can change the state.

If u are not using Redux I think it is the right way.

See that example:

[image]